# Pandas plot align x tick labels when using major_locator

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

How do I center the x tick labels in a line plot?

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), ha='center')
>> <ipython-input-161-99c31b694cb8>:7:
   UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
   ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), ha='center')
```

Pandas version: `1.4.1`

Matplotlib version: `3.5.1`

[image]

Comment: Try this: `fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=30, ha='center')`